# How to make android onCreate throw exceptions

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

I am using Jackson on android to parse a JSON file into an object, and the **object mapper (or object mapper.readvalue, I am not sure) throws an IOException**.

So I added throws IOException to my method.

```
public TextBox JsonToTextBox () throws IOException {
}
```

My problem is that I am calling that method from `onCreate`, which doesn't let me throw an exceptions. Any ideas?

[Image which explains why I cant throw exceptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0KNR.png)

I know, I can use a try catch, I was just looking how to do it by throwing an exception from onCreate, thanks for the answers though

Comment: try ... catch ... statement? or in onCreate method make a call to a custom method that throws the exception

Comment: I second try/catch and add: **log it**. If you do not want to handle it, you could wrap it into an unchecked exception. But this will probably end up in an AppCrash which is certainly not desirable.

Comment: "I was just looking how to do it by throwing an exception from onCreate" - May I ask why you want to do that?

Answer (score 4):

If you cannot handle the exception properly, you can "convert" it into a `RuntimeException` and re-throw:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...
    try {
        TextBox textBox = JsonToTextBox();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this is technically correct, I do not consider this to be the way to go for production code. Nobody likes AppCrashes. Wouldn't you agree? I know I mentioned it myself in the comments but still .... me no likey ...

Answer (score 1):

Otherwise you can catch the exception when using your method with a `try catch` block.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...
    try {
        TextBox textBox = JsonToTextBox();
    } catch (IOException) {
        //Handle exception
    }
}
```